# java modelMapper: Mapping a Collection to an Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, modelmapper

After a lot of testing and research on this topic I cannot fully solve my issue. I'm using modelmapper for entity/DTO mapping in a springboot application. I'm trying to configure my modelmapper to map a Set to a simple DTO object. I already create the a custom converter and it is working as expected:

```
Converter<Set<CategoryTl>, CategoryTlDTO> converter = new AbstractCustomConverter<Set<CategoryTl>, CategoryTlDTO>() {
        @Override
        protected D convert(S source, MappingContext<Set<CategoryTl>, CategoryTlDTO> context) {
            HashMap<String, CategoryTlDetailsDTO> map = new HashMap<>();

             source.forEach(
                    categoryTl -> map.put(categoryTl.getCatalogLanguage().getLanguage().getCode(),
                            new CategoryTlDetailsDTO(categoryTl.getName(), categoryTl.getDescription()))
            );

           return new CategoryTlDTO(map);
        }
    };
```

My issue is now to apply this converter to all "Set => CategoryTlDTO". In nested object or not. I try to create a a new TypeMap but I cannot do it because of the "Set" collection.

```
mapper.createTypeMap(Set<CategoryTl>.class (-> not possible), CategoryTlDTO.class).setConverter(converter);
```

If I add the converter directly in the model mapper it is just not working.

```
mapper.addConverter(converter);
```

Do you have any hint or a solution for this? Maybe I miss something regarding TypeToken and TypeMap Inheritance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I've not used ModelMapper, but the [docs](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/generics/) suggest you can use a TypeToken

```
Type setType = new TypeToken<Set<CategoryTl>>() {}.getType();
mapper.createTypeMap(setType, CategoryTlDTO.class).setConverter(converter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

It works for a "direct" mapping as described in the doc but I cannot set a "global converter" (a converter that will be execute each time the mapping between the Set and the object occurs) with that solution.

Comment: The converter does not match the typeMap if I use the token.